# How can I check if a timestamp entry is within a time range and with a person filter in two different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check if an entry is within a person's shift:

The data looks like this:

```
timestamp = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': ['01/02/2022 16:08:56','01/02/2022 16:23:31','01/02/2022 16:41:35','02/02/2022 16:57:41','02/02/2022 17:38:22','02/02/2022 17:50:56'],
    'Person': ['A','B','A','B','B','A']
})

shift = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['01/02/2022','02/02/2022','01/02/2022','02/02/2022'],
    'in':['13:00:00','13:00:00','14:00:00','14:00:00'],
    'out': ['21:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','22:00:00'],
    'Person': ['A','A','B','B']
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of `merge`, an efficient method is to use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
timestamp['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(timestamp['Timestamp'])

(pd.merge_asof(timestamp.sort_values(by='Timestamp'),
               shift.assign(Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(shift['Date']+' '+shift['in']),
                            ts_out=pd.to_datetime(shift['Date']+' '+shift['out']),
                            ).sort_values(by='Timestamp')
                    [['Person', 'Timestamp', 'ts_out']],
               on='Timestamp', by='Person'
              )
   .assign(in_shift=lambda d: d['ts_out'].ge(d['Timestamp']))
   .drop(columns=['ts_out']) 
)
```

output:

```
            Timestamp Person  in_shift
0 2022-01-02 16:08:56      A      True
1 2022-01-02 16:23:31      B      True
2 2022-01-02 16:41:35      A      True
3 2022-02-02 16:57:41      B      True
4 2022-02-02 17:38:22      B      True
5 2022-02-02 17:50:56      A      True
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is only one shift per person per day.

First I split the day and time from the timestamp dataframe. Then merge this with the shift dataframe on columns `Person` and `Date`. Then we only need to check whether the time from timestamp is between `in` and `out`.

```
timestamp[['Date', 'Time']] = timestamp.Timestamp.str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

df_merge = timestamp.merge(shift, on=['Date', 'Person'])

df_merge['Timestamp_in_shift'] = (df_merge.Time <= df_merge.out) & (df_merge.Time >= df_merge['in'])

df_merge.drop(columns=['Date', 'Time'])
```

Output:

```
             Timestamp Person        in       out  Timestamp_in_shift
0  01/02/2022 16:08:56      A  13:00:00  21:00:00                True
1  01/02/2022 16:41:35      A  13:00:00  21:00:00                True
2  01/02/2022 16:23:31      B  14:00:00  22:00:00                True
3  02/02/2022 16:57:41      B  14:00:00  22:00:00                True
4  02/02/2022 17:38:22      B  14:00:00  22:00:00                True
5  02/02/2022 17:50:56      A  13:00:00  21:00:00                True
```